# ValueError on Keras Variational AutoEncoder - code example not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, autoencoder

I am really new to programming neural nets and having an issue with an code example on Keras.

Keras: https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/
Github: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/vae.py

```
"""
Title: Variational AutoEncoder
Author: [fchollet](https://twitter.com/fchollet)
Date created: 2020/05/03
Last modified: 2020/05/03
Description: Convolutional Variational AutoEncoder (VAE) trained on MNIST digits.
"""

"""
## Setup
"""

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

"""
## Create a sampling layer
"""


class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


"""
## Build the encoder
"""

latent_dim = 2

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()

"""
## Build the decoder
"""

latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()

"""
## Define the VAE as a `Model` with a custom `train_step`
"""


class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder

    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction)
            )
            reconstruction_loss *= 28 * 28
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
            kl_loss *= -0.5
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
        }


"""
## Train the VAE
"""

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
mnist_digits = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test], axis=0)
mnist_digits = np.expand_dims(mnist_digits, -1).astype("float32") / 255

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(mnist_digits, epochs=30, batch_size=128)

"""
## Display a grid of sampled digits
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_latent(encoder, decoder):
    # display a n*n 2D manifold of digits
    n = 30
    digit_size = 28
    scale = 2.0
    figsize = 15
    figure = np.zeros((digit_size * n, digit_size * n))
    # linearly spaced coordinates corresponding to the 2D plot
    # of digit classes in the latent space
    grid_x = np.linspace(-scale, scale, n)
    grid_y = np.linspace(-scale, scale, n)[::-1]

    for i, yi in enumerate(grid_y):
        for j, xi in enumerate(grid_x):
            z_sample = np.array([[xi, yi]])
            x_decoded = decoder.predict(z_sample)
            digit = x_decoded[0].reshape(digit_size, digit_size)
            figure[
                i * digit_size : (i + 1) * digit_size,
                j * digit_size : (j + 1) * digit_size,
            ] = digit

    plt.figure(figsize=(figsize, figsize))
    start_range = digit_size // 2
    end_range = n * digit_size + start_range
    pixel_range = np.arange(start_range, end_range, digit_size)
    sample_range_x = np.round(grid_x, 1)
    sample_range_y = np.round(grid_y, 1)
    plt.xticks(pixel_range, sample_range_x)
    plt.yticks(pixel_range, sample_range_y)
    plt.xlabel("z[0]")
    plt.ylabel("z[1]")
    plt.imshow(figure, cmap="Greys_r")
    plt.show()


plot_latent(encoder, decoder)

"""
## Display how the latent space clusters different digit classes
"""


def plot_label_clusters(encoder, decoder, data, labels):
    # display a 2D plot of the digit classes in the latent space
    z_mean, _, _ = encoder.predict(data)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
    plt.scatter(z_mean[:, 0], z_mean[:, 1], c=labels)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.xlabel("z[0]")
    plt.ylabel("z[1]")
    plt.show()


(x_train, y_train), _ = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1).astype("float32") / 255

plot_label_clusters(encoder, decoder, x_train, y_train)
```

It's about a VAE (Variational AutoEncoder) build with Keras on the MNIST data set. When I copy the example code from GitHub I always get the following Failure (I haven't changed the code):

```
"ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize." Also I get following Warning: *"WARNING:tensorflow:Output output_1 missing from loss dictionary.
```

We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to output_1."*

More Warnings at the start:

```
"WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <bound method Sampling.call of <__main__.Sampling object at 0x000002CB451262E8>> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
Cause: 
WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform <bound method Sampling.call of <__main__.Sampling object at 0x000002CB451262E8>> and will run it as-is.
Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output."
```

So far I tried Python 3.6 and Python 3.7 on Windows 10. Is there anyone getting this error, and who knows the solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar concern. The example assumes using TF 2.3.0, check your TF version and, if possible, upgrade it.

Best